# Submitting form data to various locations based on link

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a multi-page form. Each page posts data form one to the next, where PHP stores the POST data as Session data. At the end of the table this session data is displayed in a summary table before final submission stores that session data in a MySQL database.

There are two ways to navigate away from a form page: both options to submit the form data.

1) The submit button which performs the form action, and navigates the user to the subsequent form page.

2) A page menu, from where the user can land on any other form page. I use JavaScript on the menu navigation to prompt submission:

```
$('#menu a').onclick {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

However the submit action of the form is:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="?page=survey-2">
...form fields...
</form>
```

So instigating submit only posts the updated data to the subsequent page.

In the use-case: user fills out form, arrives at summary page, sees and error uses the menu to navigate back to a page, alters it and uses the menu to jump back to summary page: nothing changes, obviously because the updated data is ONLY being submitted to the following page, NOT the destination of their navigation.

Is there a way I can use js (or anything) such that when a link is clicked in the menu, the DESTINATION of that navigation link, also receives the form data? Or alternatively, that the action of the form can submit to all the pages at once (but default navigation is to the subsequent page only)?

Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX to post the data to the handler, then go wherever you want to go with the callback

```
$('#menu a').onclick {
    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
    var handler = '?page=survey-2';
    $.post(handler,data,function(){
        window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
    })
});
```

For more about jQuery POST:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so this takes the data posts it to the "handler" (which appears to be the original destination of the data), then that data can be posted by `$.post(handler)` to anywhere I like (i.e the destination of that particular link). Is that right? I've never used AJAX before.

Comment: Yup, it can post anywhere. Just make sure its on the same domain otherwise there will be security issues.

By same domain I mean "google.com" can AJAX post to "google.com/handle.php" or "google.com/handleThis/lightly.php", but not "yahoo.com". At least by default, however there are workarounds.

Comment: Can't get this to work, could be screwing up my syntax, any chance you could see if I'm doing it right in this jsfiddle? Obviously the output doesn't work as I don't have the form etc built there, but I'm not getting anything in the context of my real code either:

http://jsfiddle.net/rFMFw/

Comment: Made some updates to your syntax. Major thing was instead of `$(element).onclick{...` it should be `$(element).click(function(){...`

http://jsfiddle.net/VwtDA/7/